# Criar consulta no query builder - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, querybuilder

Estou começando a trabalhar com Laravel e preciso fazer uma consulta no banco de dados, é uma consulta simples, mas como estou iniciando ainda não sei realizá-la.

Preciso pegar as vendas realizadas **hoje, ontem, este mês, mês anterior, ano atual e ano anterior**, mas de início preciso fazer esta consulta funcionar no Laravel, mais especificamente usando o *query builder*.

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(TotalVenda) as TotalVenda 
FROM vendas 
WHERE DATE(dtRegistro) = CURDATE()
```

Eu estou com dificuldade na junção das instruções de sintaxe, por exemplo:

```
$datas = DB::table('vendas')
    ->whereDate('dtRegistro', Carbon::now()->format('m/d/Y'))
    ->get();
```

Depois disso preciso pegar o somatório do resultado obtido, mas nesse exemplo mesmo ele já não retorna o esperado que seria os registros da data de hoje.

Comment: Bom dia Alan. Já deu uma olhada na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects)? Em qual parte você não está conseguindo avançar?

Comment: Bom dia, eu estou com dificuldade na junção das instruções de sintaxe, por exemplo:

`$datas = DB::table('vendas')->whereDate('dtRegistro', Carbon::now()->format('m/d/Y'))->get();`

depois disso preciso pegar o somatorio do resultado obtido, mas nesse exemplo mesmo ele já não retorna o esperado que seria os registros da data de hoje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, teria que ser feito com o whereRaw, para trazer a consulta que havia feito no SQL para o Laravel.

```
$total_hoje = Vendas::whereRaw('date(DataEmissao)=date(NOW())')
                                        ->whereIn('tipo', ['Devolução', 'Pedido de venda', 'Troca'])
                                        ->sum('totalvenda');

$total_ontem = Vendas::whereRaw('date(DataEmissao)=date(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))')
                                        ->whereIn('tipo', ['Devolução', 'Pedido de venda', 'Troca'])
                                        ->sum('totalvenda');
```

Comment: Você pode marcar sua resposta como a que soluciona sua dúvida